Delphi 7 Inline ASM Field Access
I cannot figure out how to access fields in a VAR parameter record.
My apologies in advance for such a simple question, but I am stumped.
After much Googling and tinkering, I am seeking the advice of my betters.
My work-around is using local variables as a transfer method from and to the fields in the VAR parameter.  This is both clumsy and very inelegant, but does work.
 program compile;

 {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

 uses
   SysUtils;

 type
   TMyRecord = record
               Name : string;
               Age  : word;
               Sex  : char;
               end;
 var
   recMyRecord : TMyRecord;

 procedure Test (var _rec : TMyRecord);
 begin
   ASM
   Mov  EBX,_rec                     // get var pointer
   Mov  EBX,[EBX]                    // set base reg to data

   Mov   AX,[EBX + _rec.age]         // crash
   Lea   EAX,EBX + _rec.age          // wrong address
   Mov   AX,offset _rec.age          // wrong address
   Lea   EAX,EBX + offset _rec.age   // wrong address
   Mov   AX,[EAX]                    // crash
   END;
 end;

 begin
   with recMyRecord do
        begin
        name := 'John Smith';
        age  := 99;
        sex  := 'M'
        end;
   Test(recMyRecord);
 end.


Drop the MOV EBX,[EBX] instruction. The initial MOV EBX, _rec instruction should be sufficient to get the reference to the record.

If this is 32-bit code I think you want something like mov EBX,[_rec] and then mov AX,[EBX + TMyRecord.age]. The first instruction gets the _rec pointer stored on the stack. The next instruction gets the age by using the offset of that member within the record and adding it to the base (EBX)

I also think Delphi may accept mov AX,[EBX + TMyRecord.age] and mov AX,[EBX].TMyRecord.age

It is important to actually run this code and test it.  You will find the results different than what is guessed.
Mov EBX, _rec does not get to the data.  It is a VAR parameter, and gets to a memory control block instead.  One must then do Mov EBX,[EBX] to actually reach the record data.  This can be seen by running and testing the code.
This is 32 bit code because I am not using any of the 64-bit register names.  Delpi 7 is a 32-bit compiler.

Happens to be the instructions you used in the ASM would compile in both 32-bit and 64-bit applications. In 64-bit apps it would fail when run and would require using RBX instead of EBX. I believe mov EBX,[_rec] mov AX,[EBX + TMyRecord.age] should work if the target application is 32-bit.

@BruceGavin: You are incorrect in your assumption. MOV EBX,_Rec will get the address of the RECORD. There's no "memory control block" for records - the parameter pushed onto the stack is the address of the actual variable. Now, if it was a CLASS instead of a RECORD, you'd have an additional level of indirection.

@BruceGavin: Your second statement - MOV EBX,[EBX] - actually gets the address of the string data for the "Name" field (as this is the first field in the record). Now, since STRING is a managed type, the Name field will most likely be NIL (zero) in an unitialized structure, which is the reason that your Mov AX,[EBX+_rec.age] crashes - it ends up accessing memory at address $00000004 which is an invalid address (all addresses below 64K are invalid as standard in Windows to traps such wrong accesses).

Note when passing by reference ( var ) you can't access member fields with variablename.member (ie _rec.age). This will actually take the location of the pointer to the record and add the offset of member to that. That isn't what you want. If you have the base address of the structure in EBX  you add that to the typename.member which will be the offset of a member within a type. You may have noticed in my comments above I use the typename when computing the offsets. ``variablename.member` access can be used when parameters are passed by value or are global.

If you pass _rec by value (drop the var) you can easily access the age by doing mov ax, [_rec.age]. Pass by value is inefficient for large data types as an entire copy is recreated on the stack to be passed to the function.

VAR parameters are mandatory for my use here, so I can modify the record data.  These are always passed as 32-bit pointer addresses to the data.
Loading EBX with the 32-bit VAR pointer then adding the record offset works correctly.  MOV AX,[EBX + TMyRecord.age] is the solution.  Note the offset is derived from the record type, and not the record being data being passed.
Thanks to HeartWare for the solution.

Thanks to HeartWare for the solution.
VAR parameters are passed in Delphi 7 as 32-bit addresses which point to the record.  Record fields are accessed as offsets from the base of the record.  These offsets are added to the VAR pointer to access each record field.
Note:  use the TYPE definition of the record for offsets.
 program compile;
 {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
 uses
   SysUtils;
 type
   TMyRecord = record
               Age   : word;
               Sex   : char;
               Birth : word;
               Name  : string;
               end;
 var
   recMyRecord : TMyRecord;
   uwWord      : word;

 procedure Test (var _ptrRecord : TMyRecord; var _ptrWord : word);
 begin
   ASM
   Mov   EBX,_ptrRecord                    // get var pointer to record

   Mov   AX,[EBX + TMyRecord.age]          // read it
   Mov   [EBX + TMyRecord.age], 100        // write it

   Mov   AX,[EBX + TMyRecord.sex]
   Mov   [EBX + TMyRecord.sex], 'M'

   Mov   AX,[EBX + TMyRecord.birth]
   Mov   [EBX + TMyRecord.birth], 1924

   Mov   EDX,_ptrWord                      // get var pointer to data
   Mov   AX,[EDX]
   Mov   [EDX],$5678
   END;

   _ptrRecord.Name := 'John Smith';
 end;

 begin
   with recMyRecord do
        begin
        age   := 0;
        sex   := ' ';
        birth := 0;
        end;
   uwWord := $1234;

   Test(recMyRecord,uwWord);               // update the record

   writeln(recMyRecord.Name);
   writeln(IntToStr(recMyRecord.age));
   writeln(recMyRecord.sex);
   writeln(IntToStr(recMyRecord.birth));
   writeln(IntToHex(uwWord,4));
   writeln;
 end.

